# Installing Hyperledger Composer on AWS Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have an AWS instance running Fabric created from an AWS Fabric template. Unfortunately, this is a Linux (not Ubuntu) instance. Now I'm trying to install the composer tools on the same instance. The docs say that I shouldn't install anything as a root, but the system won't let me install Node unless I'm a root. When I'm trying to install composer-cli (w/o sudo), I get various permission errors. Is itpossible at all to install composer on a non-Ubuntu system?

Another option is to connect to the Fabric from another instance (which is based on Ubuntu). How do you do that? Is it possible? What I need is use composer-cli tools to work with the existing Fabric instance running on AWS Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding installing on a non-ubuntu system some users have suceeded on AWS, and on Centos so it is possible.  I would work through the pre-requisites in the prereqs-ubuntu.sh script.  The particular warnings are about not using sudo or root when installing npm modules, and [this doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) may help with that problem.

Using a separate Ubuntu system as a 'client' should work, and is actually a more realistic production scenario.  You would need to make all the ports of your fabric available perhaps with firewall configuration, then on the client machine you need to create/update your connection profile (connection.json) with the addresses of the remote Fabric.

Comment: I was finally able to install Node using nvm, after that, everything was fine.