# Install Hyperledger Composer on Amazon Ec2 instance

Tags: hyperledger-composer

How to install Hyperledger Composer on Amazon Linux Ec2 instance, there are few articles online which talk about the steps on Ubuntu, but the instance I am using is more like CentOS.

Comment: see  this Stack:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50398689/installing-hyperledger-composer-on-aws-linux - also someone has posted a GIST with an install on AZ lite -> https://gist.github.com/geekoftheweek/a51eef498bd425973c7cfc23fd4788f8 and finally see this link https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125 regarding the present status of H/L Composer

Comment: also see the supported platforms FYI -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs